# Locally Path Connected Definition

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Why are the following two statements equivalent for any topological space $X$?

1) $X$ is locally path connected (meaning, it has a basis of path connected sets).

2)  Every point of $X$ has a path connected neighborhood.

Is it simply that a path connected neighborhood is an open set in the subspace topology?

Comment: Do you mean statement (1) to be just "A topological space $X$ has a basis of path-connected sets"?

Comment: @Eric:  No, I typed what I meant but what I meant was wrong apparently.

Comment: No, but what you wrote really really really doesn't make sense.   Statement (1) is simply a true statement: if $X$ has a basis of path connected sets, then $X$ is locally path connected.  The truth of (2), on the other hand, depends on what the space $X$ is.  So to say that (1) and (2) are equivalent would be to say that every topological space satisfies condition (2).

Comment: @Eric:  Point taken, I made an edit that I hope makes my question more clear.

Comment: I still highly doubt that what you've written is what you actually want to ask.  Is the following what you really want to ask: "Why is it true that for any topological space $X$, $X$ has a basis of path-connected sets iff every point of $X$ has a path connected neighborhood?"  That's the question I answered...

Comment: Since you accepted my answer, it seems my interpretation was correct.  I'm going to go ahead and clarify the question.

Comment: @Bob This is an instance of the common topological problem of "local definitions"; there are some forms which are used to define local properties, and they are in general NOT equivalent: 1) every point has a * neighborhood (this always holds if the space itself is globally *) 2) every point has an open * neighborhood 3) there is a basis of * sets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They aren't equivalent.  Indeed, any path-connected space satisfies (2), since you can take the neighborhood to just be $X$ itself.  But not every path-connected space is locally path-connected (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135483/86856, for instance).